# How to autosave main scss file?

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

When I save scss files which are imported to main sccs file - every time I should resave main scss to apply changes. How can I apply changes after saving imported scss files at once. I use VSCode Live Sass Compiler extension. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of hard to answer without seeing your project structure, but gulp has a solution for this called [gulp-sass-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-glob)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the main.scss to be updated after saving imported documents, their names should start with "_". Like "_header.scss"